# Problem trying to install (py -m pip install tables) on python 3.9.4

Tags: python-3.x, pip

i really need the "import tables" for pvlib so it can run.
But when i try to in stall on pip the "tables" i get a bunch of errors.
Does anyone can help me?

The pictures after this message are what i see, and it keeps going...

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKyCw.png)

[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHLhn.png)

[Picture 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHfn9.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says You need to have "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater". please download and give it a try - https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

also, You can get a pre-built version of PyTables for Python 3.9 Binaries for Python Extension Packages.

[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)

after downloading file run ex: `pip install tables-3.6.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl`

Comment: Dude i really thank you so much, i did the second thing u told me, so i shouldnt have to download vs and it worked perfect, i really love this community. Thank you very much!